# Symfony - Doctrine Type array

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I have a problem with my form and the problem is with my Entity. I got an error:

> Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array

and the problem is with the `$card` field.

```
public function addNewUser ($id, $firstName, $lastName)
{
    $termUsers = $this->getUserRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('nu')
        ->select('nu')
        ->where('nu.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();

    if (empty($termUsers)) {
        $termUsers = new User();
        $termUsers->setId($id);
        $termUsers->setFirstName($firstName);
        $termUsers->setLastName($lastName);
        $this->em->persist($termUsers);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    return $termUsers;
}

public function getUserAddAction()
{
    $this->requirePostParams(['id', 'firstName', 'lastName']);

    $this->get('lottoland.user')->addNewUser(
        $this->data['id'],
        $this->data['firstName'],
        $this->data['lastName']
    );

    return $this->success();
}
```

When I send parms via Postman I got the error I mentioned.

Comment: the code you show here is not related to your issue. Please paste here the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a oneToMany relation between `Card` and `User`, then:

```
# Entity/Card.php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="card")
 */
private $users;

public function __construct() 
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}


# Entity/User.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Card", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="card_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $card;
```

As for beginners, a more convenient way to create such relations, just declare the relation as I did above, then, to generate the getters and setters, use the handy symfony console command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Card
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:User
```

and this will generate for you all the needed methods.

Comment: I am aware of that, I have problem with this error.  ---Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array---